# Am I using modulus wrong? My program will always enter the if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, nested-if, leap-year

```
bool leap = false;
int leapd = 28;

if (year % 100 == 0) {
    if (year % 400 == 0) {
        leap = true;
    }
    else { leap = false; }
}

else if (year % 4 == 0) {
    leap = true;
}
else { leap = false; }
if (leap = true) {
    leapd++;
}
```

This program decides if the year entered is a leap year or not. I'm not sure why, but the program will always set `leap` to true in the end.

If the year is divisible by 100, than it is a leap year if it also is divisible by 400.

If it is not divisible by 100, it is only a leap year if you can divide the year by 4.

Comment: Most compilers have a warning for exactly the mistake you made. You might want to make sure you have a good set of default warnings enabled.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `if (leap == true)` for your last `if` statement. If you fix that, it should work. `=` is the assignment variable. So in your last `if` statement, instead of comparing `leap` and `true` using `==` you are assigning `leap` to `true` using `=`.

So your final if statement should actually be:

```
if (leap == true)
{
    leapd++;
}
```

Comment: @aschepler. Yes that's true. But I think what I have stated in my answer will be easier for the OP as it looks like he's a beginner.

Comment: `if (leap)` is not only the preferred way (if I’m not mistaken), but is also sure to prevent the same mistake from being made again.

Comment: @OleV.V. I'm a python guy so I believe in explicit rather than implicit ;)

Comment: Funny, @BOI. I’m mostly a Java guy these days and find `if (leap)`, or better, `if (isLeapYear)` the most explicit. `== true` is just redundant. I certainly never saw it when I coded C++ in the 1990’s either. Just teasing: do you then find `if ((leap == true) == true)` still more explicit? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The last loop should look like

```
if (leap == true)
{
    leapd++;
}
```

The way you currently have it will set `leap` to `True` and then evaluate the `if`. Which will always be `True`. The condition check should be `==`.